# Error while updating Node.js 16 Firebase Cloud function (Angular 14/Angular Universal/Firebase Hosting&Cloud Functions)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am trying to implement Server Side Rendering using Angular 14 with Angular Universal and Firebase Cloud Functions. I used this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/debojyoti/d75a517f77d8e5881d87553f1e493614

as a guide. I followed all the necessary steps. When trying:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting, functions
```

I get:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function ngssr(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-30T14_01_32_156Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        ngssr(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `package-lock.json` present? Is it present in source control? Is it ignored by gitignore?